# Portable floating point variable templates

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14

How to define portable high-precision floating point variable templates in c++14? The program below should print pi with `double` and `long double` precision.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <limits>

template<typename T>
constexpr T pi = T(3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197);


int main() {
  std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10) << pi<double> << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<long double>::max_digits10) << pi<long double> << std::endl;
}
```

When I compile with GCC 5.1.0 `g++ -std=c++14` I get

```
3.1415926535897931
3.141592653589793116
```

My guess is that gcc converts the number to a double and then applies the template. I don't think the `L` literal is the answer because I don't want to rewrite when I move to float128 or higher. How can I make the compiler retain all the precision?

Comment: Portable temples ? The altar may be a problem.

Comment: Its portable because it's floating. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All floating point literals, unless otherwise suffixed, are of type `double`. That you use it as an initializer for `T` (whatever `T` may be) doesn't matter, you're still going to initialize `pi` with a `double` converted to a `T`.

Suffix the literal with `l` to make it a `long double`, which is then converted to `T`.

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the purpose of the [variable templates](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3651.pdf)? They use 19 digits in the proposal, but according to you, it's completely misleading. Right?

Comment: @Mankka Yes it kind of does defeat the purpose, but on the other hand it doesn't work without templates either, try declaring an ordinary `long double` variable and initialize it similarly, and it won't work either. The compiler is probably capable of knowing that the literal should be of the correct type, but the specification says that floating point literals without suffix are of type `double` so that's what happens.

Comment: @Mankka They have noticed that problem and [added the `L` suffix in the draft standard](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/e17586537d43bd6916b93d07d9941f393964f4a6).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I hoped there would have been another way than [Boost constants](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/math/doc/html/constants.html).