# C++: boost multiprecision printing

Tags: c++, boost

I start using boost multiprecision, and I don't know what to do to display numbers properly ... I tried to do it the same way as documented:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   using namespace boost::multiprecision;
   std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<cpp_dec_float_100>::digits10);
   cpp_dec_float_100 lol = 1.28908408397287846738682223;
   std::cout << lol << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

It doesn't work. Instead of what I want I get:

```
1.2890840839728785471862693157163448631763458251953125
```

Please, help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33494620/higher-precision-floating-point-using-boost-lib-higher-then-16-digits

Comment: Why the hell does everyone know the dupe, upvote the comment and not dupevote :) Don't tell me every one had too low rep (because that would make no sense with the average number of views [tag:boost] questions get)