# Boost Using pow function with cpp_dec_float

Tags: c++, boost

I am using the `pow()` function and I am trying to compare the return to a `cpp_dec_float` but I am getting an error

Code:

```
pow(sqrt(172.601), 2) != n);
```

Error:

```
UserPath\main.cpp:21: error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are '__gnu_cxx::__promote_2<double, int, double, double>::__type {aka double}' and 'boost::multiprecision::cpp_int {aka boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<> >}')
    pow(sqrt(172.601), 2) != n))
                          ^
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of pitfalls here. See the added links at the bottom.

---

Something tells me you've been using the backend type, not a frontend adaptor (like `number<>` or `rational_adaptor<>`).

The thing works without change:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d87f85f9487a5132)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_50 n = 3;
    bool ok = pow(sqrt(172.601), 2) != n;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << ok;
}
```

Prints

```
true
```

### HOWEVER

You are mixing `double` and `cpp_dec_float`. This means that you do not gain much - if anything in the scenario - from the enhanced accuracy or decimal representation of Boost Multiprecision.

Instead consider going the whole way:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9013f7b9e555618a)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    typedef boost::multiprecision::cpp_dec_float_50 Decimal;

    Decimal n("172.601");

    Decimal other = pow(sqrt(Decimal("172.601")), 2);

    std::cout << std::setprecision(50) << n << "\n";
    std::cout << std::setprecision(50) << other << "\n";

    bool equal = (abs(other - n) < std::numeric_limits<Decimal>::epsilon());

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << equal;
}
```

Prints:

```
172.601
172.601
true
```

Note the CRUCIAL initialization from *text*, not a `double` literal!

---

Background info:

- [What is the most effective way for float and double comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison)
- [higher precision floating point using boost lib (higher then 16 digits)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33494620/higher-precision-floating-point-using-boost-lib-higher-then-16-digits/33494853#33494853)

Comment: Went the extra mile and added background information links